# How to extract substrings from this string?

Tags: string, r, substring

The string is 
[image]
And I want to get substrings "11","1.1","282". Can anyone show me how to do this in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I believe `strsplit(x," +")[[1]]` will do it.  (the regular expression `" +"` denotes one or more spaces; `strsplit` applies to character vectors, and returns a list with the splitted version of each element in the vector, so `[[1]]` extracts the first (and only) component)

Comment: Also, `"[[:space:]]+"` will deal with all types of white space characters: spaces, tabs, line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

```
> x = "11  1.1     282"
> res <- strsplit(x, " +")
> res
[[1]]
[1] "11"  "1.1" "282"

>
```